# In windows, need to write a batch command to recursively search a folder

Tags: batch-file

i have a list of file names , i want to search these files in a folder and copy them to a different folder maintaining the subdirectories as it is

For example

```
C:\test |
 +---folder1 | test2.txt | test3.txt |
 +---folder2 | test4.txt | test5.txt |
 ---folder3 test6.txt
```

here if i my list of file are test3.txt, text5.txt, test6.txt (these could be 100 file names even)

then batch command should recursively search the C:\test folder and create another folder like below with these files alone.

```
C:\testout |
+---folder1 | test3.txt 
+---folder2 | test5.txt 
---folder3 test6.txt
```

List of filenames to be searched will be in a text file.

Comment: What is the logic in the deciding of where the text documents go?

Comment: Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: @Deepak You need to clarify what sets apart files test3.txt and test5.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to what you ask, and it is much simpler than the code required to do exactly as you ask.

It takes the filenames in `file.txt` and copies them into `"d:\testout\test\..."` and duplicates the directory structure.

When it's done it just needs a drag and drop if you don't want the extra `test` folder.

There is a possibility of false positives if your files have extra extensions.
For example `test2.txt.exe` will be mistaken for `test2.txt` and also be copied.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("file.txt") do (
for /r "d:\test" %%b in ("%%a*") do xcopy "%%b" "d:\testout\%%~pb" /s
)
pause
```

**Edit: code to speed up network access** - untested

```
@echo off
pushd "\\server\share" || goto :EOF
dir /b /s /a-d >"%temp%\filelist.tmp"
del "%temp%\filelist2.tmp" 2>nul
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\folder\file.txt") do (
   findstr /i /e /c:"%%a" "%temp%\filelist.tmp" >>"%temp%\filelist2.tmp"
)
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in ("%temp%\filelist2.tmp") do (
   xcopy "%%b:%%c" "d:\testout\%%~pc" 
)
del "%temp%\filelist.tmp" "%temp%\filelist2.tmp" >nul
popd
pause
```

Comment: I am trying to search in a network path inside a folder of 152,000 documents , list of files to be searched is 1500, after 5 hours it has only found 50 documents, is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: It's always useful to reveal the actual task, so helpers don't have to write code twice. :)  Try the added code above - it is not tested.